# Determine which of four date ranges a single date range overlaps

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, count

I have Subscriptions that can last anywhere (as far as my output should be concerned) from 1 to 4 fiscal quarters (could also be seen as four date ranges)

I'm using Arizona Fiscal Quarters:

- Q1: Jul 1st - Sep 30th
- Q2: Oct 1st - Dec 31st
- Q3: Jan 1st - Mar 31st
- Q4: Apr 1st - Jun 30th

**What I need to figure out is how many subscriptions are active in each quarter based on the subscriptions start and end dates.**

For example, using (YYYY-MM-DD), I have:

- A subscription that starts on 2016-07-06 and ends on 2017-02-22 I should be able to see I have a subscription active in Q1, Q2, and Q3.
- Another subscription that starts on 2016-10-18 and ends on 2016-10-24 would only be seen as active for Q2
- Finally, a subscription that starts on 2016-09-28 but has ***no*** end date would be seen as active for Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4 (so whatever starting quarter all the way to Q4)

Below is my current SQL Server Script, and here it is on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a11a/4/0):

```
WITH SubscriptionInfo AS
(
    SELECT
        [Subscriptions].[Customer_Id]
        ,[DistributorTypes].[Name]                              AS [Distributor Type]
        ,[Customers].Zip_Id
        ,[Subscriptions].[UnsubscribeReason_Id]
        ,[Subscriptions].[Id]                                   AS [Subscription ID]
        ,CONVERT(DATE, [Subscriptions].[StartDate])             AS [Subscription Start Date]
        ,CONVERT(DATE, [Subscriptions].[EndDate])               AS [Subscription End Date]
        ,[PriorityLevels].PriorityLevel                         AS [Priority Level]
        ,CONVERT(DATE, [SubscriptionPriorityLevels].StartDate)  AS [Priority Level Start Date]
        ,CONVERT(DATE, [SubscriptionPriorityLevels].EndDate)    AS [Priority Level End Date]
        ,[FundingSources].[Name]                                AS [Funding Source]
        ,CONVERT(DATE, [SubscriptionFundingSources].StartDate)  AS [SubscriptionFundingSources Start Date]
        ,CONVERT(DATE, [SubscriptionFundingSources].EndDate)    AS [SubscriptionFundingSources End Date]
    FROM [Subscriptions]

    LEFT JOIN [SubscriptionPriorityLevels]
        ON [SubscriptionPriorityLevels].Subscription_Id = Subscriptions.Id
    LEFT JOIN [PriorityLevels]
        ON [PriorityLevels].Id = SubscriptionPriorityLevels.PriorityLevel_Id
    LEFT JOIN [SubscriptionFundingSources]
        ON [SubscriptionFundingSources].Subscription_Id = Subscriptions.Id
    LEFT JOIN [FundingSources]
        ON [FundingSources].Id = [SubscriptionFundingSources].FundingSource_Id
    LEFT JOIN [Customers]
        ON [Customers].Id = [Subscriptions].Customer_Id
    LEFT JOIN [DistributorTypes]
        ON [DistributorTypes].Id = Customers.DistributorType_Id

    WHERE
        ([Subscriptions].StartDate >= '2016-07-01')             -- Dummy dates, would later be parameters
        AND ([Subscriptions].EndDate <= '2017-06-30'
            OR [Subscriptions].EndDate IS NULL)
        AND ([PriorityLevels].PriorityLevel IN (2, 3))          -- Only care about these two levels
        AND ([Customers].DistributorType_Id = 1)                -- Distributor Type: Number One Distrubition
        AND ([SubscriptionFundingSources].FundingSource_Id = 2) -- Funding Source: First Bank
)

SELECT
    [SubscriptionInfo].Customer_Id
    ,[SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription ID]
    ,MAX([SubscriptionInfo].[Priority Level]) AS [Highest Priority Level]
    ,CASE   -- Determine which fiscal quarter each Subscription Start Date belongs to
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription Start Date]) IN (7, 8, 9)       THEN 1  -- July, August, September
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription Start Date]) IN (10, 11, 12)    THEN 2  -- October, November, December
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription Start Date]) IN (1, 2, 3)       THEN 3  -- January, Feburary, March
                                                                                    ELSE 4  -- April, May, June
    END AS [Fiscal Quarter Start Date]
    ,CASE   -- Determine which fiscal quarter each Subscription Start Date belongs to
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription End Date]) IN (7, 8, 9)         THEN 1  -- July, August, September
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription End Date]) IN (10, 11, 12)      THEN 2  -- October, November, December
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription End Date]) IN (1, 2, 3)         THEN 3  -- January, Feburary, March
                                                                                    ELSE 4  -- April, May, June
    END AS [Fiscal Quarter End Date]
FROM [SubscriptionInfo]


GROUP BY
    [SubscriptionInfo].Customer_Id
    ,[SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription ID]
    ,CASE   -- Group Subscription Start Date's into Fiscal Quarters
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription Start Date]) IN (7, 8, 9)       THEN 1  -- July, August, September
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription Start Date]) IN (10, 11, 12)    THEN 2  -- October, November, December
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription Start Date]) IN (1, 2, 3)       THEN 3  -- January, Feburary, March
                                                                                    ELSE 4  -- April, May, June
    END
    ,CASE   -- Group Subscription End Date's into Fiscal Quarters
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription End Date]) IN (7, 8, 9)         THEN 1  -- July, August, September
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription End Date]) IN (10, 11, 12)      THEN 2  -- October, November, December
        WHEN MONTH([SubscriptionInfo].[Subscription End Date]) IN (1, 2, 3)         THEN 3  -- January, Feburary, March
                                                                                    ELSE 4  -- April, May, June
    END

ORDER BY
    [SubscriptionInfo].Customer_Id
```

So far I'm able to identify in what fiscal quarter a subscription started and what fiscal quarter it ended.

I want to be able to count how many subscriptions were active in each quarter.

**Desired Output:**

```
| FirstQuarter | SecondQuarter | ThirdQuarter | FourthQuarter |
|--------------|---------------|--------------|---------------|
|            2 |             1 |            3 |             3 |
```

Comment: Why not create a Quarters table that contains the FiscalYear, QuarterNumber and StartDate? Then you can easily determine what quarters a given subscription covers.

Comment: @SeanLange Forgive me, I'm not sure I'm following. Is something like this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/acc61/1) what you're suggesting? Can you expand on how would I use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a table describing the quarters' start and end dates as @Sean Lange suggested, you just need to compare your subscriptions' start and end date to the quarters' start and end date and then count them up where they overlap.  Basically, two ranges have some overlap if A.Start < B.End and A.End > B.Start.

Here's a complete example of the pattern.

```
-------------------------
-- construct the quarters table (taken from the SQL Fiddle in comments above)

DECLARE @FiscalDate Table
(
  Id INT NOT NULL,
  FiscalYear INT NOT NULL,
  FiscalQuarter INT NOT NULL,
  QuarterStartDate DATE NOT NULL,
  QuarterEndDate DATE NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

INSERT INTO @FiscalDate 
  (Id, FiscalYear, FiscalQuarter, QuarterStartDate, QuarterEndDate)
VALUES
  ( 1, 2016, 1, '2016-07-01', '2016-09-30')
  ,(2, 2016, 2, '2016-10-01', '2016-12-31')
  ,(3, 2017, 3, '2017-01-01', '2017-03-31')
  ,(4, 2017, 4, '2017-04-01', '2017-06-30')
;


-------------------------
--Get some random test data to imitate subscriptions ranges

DECLARE @tempSet Table(a date, b date)
INSERT INTO @tempSet SELECT TOP 15
    dateadd(dd, ROUND(365 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid())), 0), '2016-07-01') as a
    , dateadd(dd, ROUND(365 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid())), 0), '2016-07-01') as b
FROM sysobjects

-------------------------
-- Fix our random data a little (start date needs to be before end date)

DECLARE @DateRanges Table(StartDate date, EndDate date)
INSERT INTO @DateRanges
SELECT a, b FROM @tempset WHERE a <= b UNION SELECT b, a FROM @tempset WHERE b < a


-------------------------
-- Show our Date ranges in a useful order for review
SELECT * FROM @DateRanges ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate

-------------------------
-- Show our by-quarter counts.


SELECT
    fd.FiscalQuarter
    , count(*) as ActiveSubsCount
FROM
    @FiscalDate fd

    JOIN

    @DateRanges dr
        on fd.QuarterStartDate < dr.EndDate
        and fd.QuarterEndDate >= dr.StartDate
GROUP BY
    fd.FiscalQuarter


-------------------------
-- and in your desired output (without your quarters table)
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN '2016-07-01' < dr.EndDate AND '2016-09-30' >= dr.StartDate THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FirstQuarter 
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN '2016-10-01' < dr.EndDate AND '2016-12-31' >= dr.StartDate THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS SecondQuarter  
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN '2017-01-01' < dr.EndDate AND '2017-03-31' >= dr.StartDate THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ThirdQuarter 
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN '2017-04-01' < dr.EndDate AND '2017-06-30' >= dr.StartDate THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS FourthQuarter 
FROM
    @DateRanges dr
```

Comment: Wow, this is very helpful! I've converted your code to MS SQL Server in yet another [SQL Fiddle Script](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa2bb/3), and I'm pretty sure you've done what I needed, and made it look easy! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much what I was saying. Well done.